# Configure SpringBoot to connect to AWS RDS Postgres using IAM

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, amazon-rds, amazon-iam, liquibase

I am having issues connecting to RDS Posgress using IAM. There are a number of articles online explaining how to extend HikariDataSource and override getPassword method to get new password every 14 minutes, etc..., but not a single one of them explain how to get liquibase part of the project connected. I was given a user id and an endpoint to connect to. My app is running in Kubernetes on AWS and I am being told all the IAM configuration has been completed correctly (I have no way to verify this but will take their word for it)

So here is what I got so far

1. I extended HikariDataSource as explained [here](https://blog.jdriven.com/2021/06/configure-hikari-connection-pool-when-using-rds-iam/)
2. I configured application.yml with user name and an end point:

```
  liquibase:
    url: jdbc:postgresql://...hidden.....us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com/..dbname..?ssl=true&sslmode=require
    user: ...hidden....
    password:
    change-log: classpath:db/changelog/databaseChangeLog.xml
    enabled: true
    liquibase-schema: ...schema name...
    parameters:
      schema: ...schema name...

  datasource:
    url: jdbc:postgresql://...hidden.....us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com/..dbname..?ssl=true&sslmode=require
    user: ...hidden....
    password:
    driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
    hikari:
      schema: ...schema name...
      max-lifetime: 60000
```

3. I figured since regular datasource is needing change, so does liquibase, so I did the following

```
@Configuration
public class RdsAimConfiguration {
    @Bean(name = "liquibaseDataSource")
    public RdsIamDataSource liquibaseDataSource() {
        return new RdsIamDataSource();
    }

}
```

Trying this out I get this error

```
Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'liquibase' defined in class path resource 
[org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/liquibase/LiquibaseAutoConfiguration$LiquibaseConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: PAM authentication failed for user \"...user name....\"","logger_name":"org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext
```

Any help and direction on how to get a SpringBoot app with liquibase running in AWS connecting to RDS Postgres with IAM is greatly appreciated

Comment: It appears that defining liquibaseDataSource bean is not required. Once I configured spring.datasource.type to point to a new datasource class liquibase seems to pick that up. Although I am having other issues now, I think the liquibase problem is resolved.